# How to delete last added element from localstorage json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, local-storage

I have tried the below code to delete last added array(Users array)object.It works in console.but it doesnt delete the data from localstorage.Any help would be appreciated

```
var delRecord = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("MyRecords"));
for (var d = 0; d < delRecord .length; d++) {
        delRecord [d].Users.pop();          
}
```

Is pop() method will work or any suggestions?

Comment: please add your arrays and values to the code

Comment: given a sample code.I have localstorage as json object.i want to know how to delete item from that json array.[Values sample](http://jsfiddle.net/nilisha7/7kqne93o/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the result back to the local storage:

```
var delRecord = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("MyRecords"));
for (var d = 0; d < delRecord .length; d++) {
        delRecord[d].Users.pop();          
}

localStorage.setItem("MyRecords", JSON.stringify(delRecord));
```

Comment: Great! @rdubya this is wat i want.